# Custom UI: psd to iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, photoshop

looking at dribbble, I have started to ask myself, how I would implement a very custom UI in Xcode as a back-end dev.

Assuming, I have a photoshop file with layers with the whole mockup, how would i basically port it to iOS?

I am curious for some answers!

Comment: In other words, "How do I write an iOS app?"  This question is way too broad.

Comment: @robmayoff I don't think the question is comparable to "How do i Write an iOS app". I was asking how the **workflow** for creating custom ui design would look like

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As hotpaw2 rightly mentioned, you create each object (button, textfields, segment control, etc..) in photoshop and apply desired effects (**Drop shadow, Gradient, Stroke, Inner Shadow** etc..) .

To create a button draw a rectangle shape (with radius if needed) and apply the effects to that layer from **Layer** > **Layer Styles** >
**Drop Shadow**.

Most important is to adhere to **Apple's HIG guidelines** while designing the custom UI otherwise your app may get rejected.

Once the button is ready in Photoshop in the Layers windows choose that layer, goto **Paths** tab and right click that layer and choose "**Make Selection**", Select **Copy Merged** from the Edit menu and create a new document and paste the copies layer and choose **Save it for Web** from the File menu, save it as **PNG24** with transparency.

```
 // Image with cap insets sample code:
 UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton"]  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16, 0, 16)];
```

This makes the left and right 16 pixels of the button image are not scaled or resized and the center part of the image to be scaled.

All the Best.

Comment: In photoshop: what if I have some layer blending option like shadow or border which comes out of the shape border, what is the best photoshop way to cover this extra effects,

Answer (score 2):

You could convert each photoshop layer into a PNG file, with transparency if needed, then assign the PNG images to various UIViews or UIControls, either in Objective C code, or using the Xcode Interface Builder tool.

Comment: Okay… how about costum effects & shadows?

Comment: You might want to ask this as a new question with a lot more specific details about what types of effects you want, and what you want these effects to do, if anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is the perfect way to do that is to convert your psd file to html file with css and images (of course), and after you will crate a converter that get this files as input and generate a xcode files (.h, .m and xib). I think that this kind of converter will help us (developers) to do the job and save much time doing the integra